# Rasa Core, load bot in Spyder IPython console

Tags: python, ipython, spyder

Is there a way I can load my rasa_core chatbot in my spyder console? Its easier for me to read and I can adjust the colors better.

Currently, I use Anacondo prompt to load my chatbot.

Here is the code that is used:

```
python -m rasa_core.run -d models/current/dialogue -u models/current/nlu
```

It would help if someone can suggest the code I can input in Spyder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typing the following into your ipython console should work assuming you've set your working directory properly.

`%run -m rasa_core.run -d models/current/dialogue -u models/current/nlu`